# PHP & Unity - Moving Info back and forth

Tags: php, unity-game-engine, web

I posted not long ago and decided to make another thread.

In our application we ask the players to create a new account, when they do we add this information to our DB.

The next step is to now grab the account they created, so that we can add more data to it. So the player creates an account with us, after this is done we then login with Google Play Services, and we now need to add info from google to the account they created, locale, id, etc

My problem here being new to php is im not sure on the correct way to do this so im asking for some guidance on it and have a couple of questions that may or may not make any sense.

1. When a user creates an account i now need to reference and keep a hold of this account they created so that we can easily access and edit/add info to it. How would you accomplish this?
2. When i need information from the database to display in the application how would i grab this info specific to the player and read it directly into unity? I think i could use the JsonEncode but im not sure if this is the most efficient way to do this.

There is more but i don't want to ask to much all at once haha.

Thanks for any and all help.

John

```
    <?php
/// Check to make sure there is data in these fields
/// Only accept user when they have confirmed thier email
error_reporting('E_All');
include 'db_header.php';
$error = '';
$firstName = $_GET['firstName'];
$lastName = $_GET['lastName'];
$email = $_GET['email'];
$password = $_GET['password'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO Player (FirstName, LastName, Email, Password)
VALUES ('$firstName', '$lastName', '$email', '$password')";

// Here i need to make sure this is correct
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
{
    $id = $conn->insert_id;
    echo "Welcome " . $firstName . " You are now an Rcader! ";
}
else
{
    //echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    $error = $conn->error;
    echo $error;
}
```

Comment: Code of your current php datalayer would be nice. All I can say with current information is... 1) huh? Save it in the db, I guess? 2) json will work nicely. Save it maybe something like : id, jsondata, lastmodified?, etc

Comment: Added the code im using to create a new user, not sure this is relevant though?

Comment: Where is the code for getting data from the db? 

I'm not sure what you are asking for, but it seems like you want to keep the connection open for the entire login session... I don't know if this is possible, safe or desirable. 

You can store data such as names in variables and display them in unity, but when you want to make a change in the database you should always 

Open connection -> [UPDATE](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-update-query.htm) -> Close connection

Comment: Also if it suits you better, you can choose to only update the DB at the end of every login-session, or make your connection in a dedicated method.
That way you won't have to constantly connect to DB if you have *volatile* data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should need to learn about the basic PHP and Unity3d integration through this simple unity3d Tut at unity wiki which is [**Server Side High Score**](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Server_Side_Highscores).

Now come to your questions:

You should first authenticate user by asking user name and p/w in unity3d if his login is valid save its id/primary key into **[player prefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html)**. Later use this player prefs value to store user specific information into database. You can also use this player prefs value to retrieve data from database. And never forget to remove player prefs values before exiting the game.

Comment: Thank you guys! Thats helped a lot. Im slowly wrapping my head around this and quite excited with the new language :D Cheers